# People API Get Method don't return phone number?

Tags: rest, get, google-people-api

I have been testing a People API get method.

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

I noticed that it is not returning the phone number.

Other data as well:
`addresses,biographies,braggingRights,events,imClients,interests,occupations,organizations,relations,relationshipInterests,relationshipStatuses,residences,sipAddresses,skills,taglines,userDefined`.

I tried all the scopes, but it doesn't help. It's really easy to test.

I'd like to return the phone number. Last week it was working perfectly with only 4 scopes (April 9).

[image: working]

How can I manage to get the phone number?

Answer (score 5):

As for the Google phone number - it is a configuration thing that's need to be done:

For 'user.phonenumbers.read' scope the documentation of people API states - 'your app be given read access to the authenticated user's phone numbers in their Google profile'.
But by 'Google profile' it indicates the Google Plus Profile which is completely different form their core google profile - My Account. People API is fetching information only from the Google Plus Profile..

So even if a user has his/her contact details added in My Account, the People API will not fetch their phone numbers unless they have added them manually in their Google Plus Profile.

So, please add the phone number to the user Google Plus Profile and try again